# Autobackup access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have this code which i got somewhere (credit to the author) and modified a bit in order to make an automated backup of my database every 7 days.

```
Function fMakeBackup() As Boolean

    Dim Source As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim retval As Integer
    
On Error GoTo sysBackup_Err

    Source = CurrentDb.name

    Target = "d:\" 
    Target = Target & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "  " 
    Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb" 

  If DateDiff("d", DLookup("[BackupDate]", "WinAutoBackup", "[BckID] =1"), Date) = 7 Then

    retval = 0
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
       DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE WinAutoBackup SET WinAutoBackup.BackupDate = Date();"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    MsgBox "Backup successfull. Next auto backup in 7 days"

  Else
    Exit Function
  End If
  
sysBackup_Exit:
Exit Function

sysBackup_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, , "sysBackup()"
Resume sysBackup_Exit
End Function
```

how can i modify the path, so that all backup files go into a folder called backups inside the
same directory as the main backend database file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Target = "d:\"
Target = Target & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "  " 
Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb"
```

with this where `f:\databasefolder` is the drive/folder holding your backend database file:

```
Target = "f:\databasefolder\backups\" 
Target = Target & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhnn") & ".accdb"
```

Comment: Thx Gustav. But I might need to modify this path anytime I need to used the db on another computer. Especially if there is no drive f:\. Is there a way to let the system identify the path on its own, so that there won't be a need to always modify the vba code?

Answer (score 0):

Use CurrentProject.path to return where the database is being used from.